# Sbt install: You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured

Tags: sbt

Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    Host repo.typesafe.com not found. url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

```
Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

Host oss.sonatype.org not found. url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

    module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3

==== local: tried

  /root/.ivy2/local/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

  http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

==== Maven Central: tried

  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

  https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

    :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found

    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /root/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jna 3.2.3

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer is found in the log:

**You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.**

If you can use another proxy server you can set it in the sbt start script:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>
```

Comment: I figured the problem by setting environment variables, both http_proxy and https_proxy.

Comment: That's another possibility, yes. But if you need the proxy only for sbt, you can configure it in the sbt script (as shown above).

Comment: Hi @Christian, I have the same problem here. but I don't have any valid proxyHost and proxyPort. How can I solve it? I have also asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744072/how-to-run-scala-code-in-spark-container-using-docker) !?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't know the proxyHost you have to set?

Answer (score 5):

For me, this problem was caused by a temporary issue with our company's DNS server. I mention this only because this question is one of the top results when searching online for the above error message.

Comment: Hi Dylan, I still have problem. I have configured the command with one of proxy which exists on [this site](https://free-proxy-list.net/). But it doesn't solve my problem. I don't know what to do. Would you please guide me to solve my problem?
[my stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744072/how-to-run-scala-code-in-spark-container-using-docker) and [my github issue](https://github.com/sindbach/mongodb-spark-docker/issues/5)

Answer (score 2):

In `WINDOWS` environment, simply add following line in the `sbt/conf/sbtconfig.txt`

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=PROXYHOST 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=PROXYPORT 
-Dhttp.proxyUser=USERNAME 
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=XXXX
```

or the Https equivalent

```
-Dhttps.proxyHost=PROXYHOST 
-Dhttps.proxyPort=PROXYPORT 
-Dhttps.proxyUser=USERNAME 
-Dhttps.proxyPassword=XXXX
```

or simply set following variable on dos command prompt

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=XXXXXXX -Dhttp.proxyPort=YYYY -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=XXXXXXX -Dhttps.proxyPort=YYYY -Dhttps.proxySet=true
```

Comment: set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=XXXXXXX -Dhttp.proxyPort=YYYY -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttps.proxyHost=XXXXXXX -Dhttps.proxyPort=YYYY -Dhttps.proxySet=true works fine thanks

Comment: I still have problem. I have configured the command with one of proxy which exists on [this site](https://free-proxy-list.net/). But it doesn't solve my problem. I don't know what to do. Would you please guide me to solve my problem?
[my stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57744072/how-to-run-scala-code-in-spark-container-using-docker) and [my github issue](https://github.com/sindbach/mongodb-spark-docker/issues/5)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the web location http to https in **ivysettings.xml** file.