# How to run scala code in spark container using docker?

Tags: scala, docker, apache-spark, ubuntu

I have created a Spark container using the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
default-jdk \
nano \
wget && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash ubuntu

ENV HOME /home/ubuntu
ENV SPARK_VERSION 2.4.3
ENV HADOOP_VERSION 2.6
ENV MONGO_SPARK_VERSION 2.2.0
ENV SCALA_VERSION 2.11

WORKDIR ${HOME}

ENV SPARK_HOME ${HOME}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}
ENV PATH ${PATH}:${SPARK_HOME}/bin

COPY files/times.json /home/ubuntu/times.json
COPY files/README.md /home/ubuntu/README.md
COPY files/examples.scala /home/ubuntu/examples.scala
COPY files/initDocuments.scala /home/ubuntu/initDocuments.scala

RUN chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/*
USER ubuntu

# get spark
RUN wget http://apache.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/spark/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}/spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz && \
tar xvf spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz

RUN rm -fv spark-${SPARK_VERSION}-bin-hadoop${HADOOP_VERSION}.tgz
```

I also have two files written in Scala programming language and that sounds new to me. The problem is that the container just knows java and doesn't have any other command installed. Is there any way to run the Scala without installing any program on container?

The file names are `examples.scala` and `initDocuments.scala`. Here is initDocuments.scala file:

```
import com.mongodb.spark._
import com.mongodb.spark.config._
import org.bson.Document 

val rdd = MongoSpark.load(sc)

if (rdd.count<1){
    val t = sc.textFile("times.json")
    val converted = t.map((tuple)=>Document.parse(tuple))
    converted.saveToMongoDB(WriteConfig(Map("uri"->"mongodb://mongodb/spark.times")))
    println("Documents inserted.")
} else {
    println("Database 'spark' collection 'times' is not empty. Maybe you've loaded a data into the collection previously ? skipping process. ")
}
System.exit(0);
```

I have also tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
spark-shell --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://mongodb:27017/spark.times" --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://mongodb/spark.output" --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_${SCALA_VERSION}:${MONGO_SPARK_VERSION} -i ./initDocuments.scala
```

**Error:**

```
Ivy Default Cache set to: /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/cache
The jars for the packages stored in: /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/jars
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/home/ubuntu/spark-2.4.3-bin-hadoop2.6/jars/ivy-2.4.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11 added as a dependency
:: resolving dependencies :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent-d0f95242-e9b9-4d49-8dde-42afc7c55e9a;1.0
        confs: [default]
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
You probably access the destination server through a proxy server that is not well configured.
:: resolution report :: resolve 40879ms :: artifacts dl 0ms
        :: modules in use:
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
        |       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        |      default     |   1   |   0   |   0   |   0   ||   0   |   0   |
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.pom

        Host repo1.maven.org not found. url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar

        Host dl.bintray.com not found. url=https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.pom

        Host dl.bintray.com not found. url=https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar

                module not found: org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0

        ==== local-m2-cache: tried

          file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.pom

          -- artifact org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0!mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar:

          file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar

        ==== local-ivy-cache: tried

          /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/local/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0!mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar:

          /home/ubuntu/.ivy2/local/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar

        ==== central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.pom

          -- artifact org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0!mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar

        ==== spark-packages: tried

          https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.pom

          -- artifact org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0!mongo-spark-connector_2.11.jar:

          https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven/org/mongodb/spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.11/2.2.0/mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.2.0.jar

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [unresolved dependency: org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0: not found]
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitUtils$.resolveMavenCoordinates(SparkSubmit.scala:1306)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveMavenDependencies(DependencyUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:315)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

**PS:** I have tried to change the proxy address using the following command but I think that I don't have a good proxy for my usage. I would be thankful if anyone could help me to run a well configured proxy to solve my downloading problem.

```
export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dhttp.proxyHost=yourserver -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password"
```

Comment: build and run jar.

Comment: @Lamanus would you explain how? I am newbie to scala

Comment: it is similar to java. you cannot run scala code directly and need to build first.

Comment: @Lamanus I am not familiar with java, too. There is no sbt, maven and etc. installed. I have just java installed on that container. Would you please explain the steps as an answer?

Comment: For proxy configuration, you might want to check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36676395).

Comment: Hi @JoePallas, I have tried them but I'm looking for a valid IP and Port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message that you have below

```
:: org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.2.0: not found
```

It indicates that the package is missing. Checking on currently available [MongoDB Connector for Spark](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/) packages, confirms that the package is no longer available (replaced with patched v2.2.6).

You can check an updated example of MongoDB Spark connector with Docker on [sindbach/mongodb-spark-docker](https://github.com/sindbach/mongodb-spark-docker).

Additional information: 
[spark-shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell) is a REPL (Read-Evaluate-Print Loop) tool. It is an interactive shell used by programmers to interact with a framework. You don't need to explicitly execute `build` for execution. When you specify `--packages` argument of `spark-shell` it will automatically fetch the package and include it in the environment of your shell.

Comment: Hi Wan, thank you for updating the repository and give a good support. I still doesn't work as expected I face with new errors like `org.mongodb.spark#mongo-spark-connector_2.11;2.4.1: not found`. It's better for me to add the required files manually. because I have checked the possible solutions and they didn't help me. As an example here is a [link to see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36676395)